# How to prevent Xcode's re-indent (Control + i) feature from scrolling to the bottom?

Tags: xcode, xcode11

After writing some code, I usually select all lines then tap <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>.

This re-indents the code, but annoyingly scrolls all the way to the bottom.

Is there a way to prevent Xcode from scrolling down so I can preserve my scroll position?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution as I'm having the same issue too.

Comment: Still annoying.